# How to change table name in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

i want to change table name in mysql it seems easy but every times gives a error

I want to change table name
    from `qwerty` to `qwerty_2`

So, how can i do so?

Any help will be appreciated thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650370/rename-a-table-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways

```
ALTER TABLE qwerty RENAME qwerty_2;
```

or

```
RENAME TABLE qwerty TO qwerty_2;
```